# Any globally unique signature in Ardupilot hardware, or Arduino in general?

Tags: arduino, ardupilot

I have several [APM 2.5 boards](http://store.3drobotics.com/products/apm-2-5-kit) and need to identify them based on some globally unique hardware signature that does not change with programming.

Arduinos and atmel AVR chips in general [do not have](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45104.0) (also [this thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45060.0)) an accessible serial number.

However, it seems that the Ardupilot has so many integrated sensors and other ICs that one of them must have something unique I can use ( [see schematic](http://stuff.storediydrones.com/APM_v252_RELEASE.zip) )!

I will be checking datasheets for MPU-6000, HMC5883L-TR and MS5611, but in the meantime, if someone has already figured this one out, please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll be darned. A serial number shows up in dmesg when you plug the thing in. I checked two boards that the number was different, so hopefully these are globally unique.

```
me@mycompy:~/arducopter/MissionPlanner$ dmesg|tail                                                                                                                                                   
[26581.627967] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues
[26583.020822] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[26583.115672] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0010
[26583.115682] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[26583.115689] usb 1-1.2: Product: Arduino Mega 2560
[26583.115696] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[26583.115702] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 64033353830351A0B122
[26583.116485] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```